# how to send HTTP request with APIKEY

Tags: fetch, aws-api-gateway, api-key

I have an API Gateway created to trigger my lambda function. I am trying to secure the invoke URL. I understand that we can use the Lambda Authorizer or the APIKEY. I am trying to use the API key but not sure how to pass the API key using fetch.

I have also linked the API to the API Keys and the usage Plans.

I am trying to access the URL from the client-side.

invokeurl is referring to my Invoke URL which will return the JSON object.
egkeyname is my key value which I am not able to share.

Client.py:

```
onMount(async () => {
    const res = await fetch('invokeurl',{
        method:'get',
        headers: new Headers ({
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'OPTIONS,POST,GET',
            'X-API-KEY' :'egkeyname' 
        })
    });  //wait until the promise return result
    data = await res.json();    
});
```

But I get an error:

```
Access to fetch at '..invoke ur...' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

GET https:invokeurl net::ERR_FAILED

My lambda function:

```
  responseObject = {}
  responseObject['statusCode'] = 200
  responseObject['headers']={}
  responseObject['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
  responseObject['headers']['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  responseObject['headers']['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'OPTIONS,POST,GET'
return responseObject
```

How do I access the URL with the APIkey?

Comment: Looks like a CORS issue. Have you enabled CORS on your API? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Comment: Yup i have enabled on my API side. above is my edited code with my api

Answer (score 0):

Solved it on my own. I was using the wrong information in the Header.

It should be:

```
onMount(async () => {
    const res = await fetch('invokeurl',{
        method:'get',
        headers: new Headers ({
            'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization',
            'Origin' : '*',
            'Access-Control-Request-Method':'OPTIONS,POST,GET',
            'X-API-KEY' :'egkeyname' 
        })
    });  //wait until the promise return result
    data = await res.json();    
});
```